# Blender batch processing

Tags: python, blender

I have quite some STL files to render as turntable in Blender.
I need to apply to each model the same setting(scale, lights,shading, etc..)

Is it somehow possible to do a "batch process" of all the models with the same setting?
I know I can use python to re-create the same scene/setting but I wonder is there is something easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way around using the integrated Python Interface, which amongst others was made to facilitate exactly such problems.

However, if programmatically setting all the "outer" scene parameters (such as lighting) is too much work, you may consider providing a standard scene that is set up using the classic "click-by-click"-way. Using such default template, you then could think of selectively loading and unloading your STL files (e.g. using a simple loop) into it, where you may have only little additional steps to take (e.g. scaling, triggering the final render). Loading all STLs at once and toggling their visibility in the renders is also a way to go, yet with potentially higher memory loads than integrating and deleting them one by one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with the template route and program the rest.